# Lexmark Printer stop working after Upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, 14.04, printing, lexmark

My parents have a Lexmark Pinnacle 901 Pro Printer/Scanner. Since their Ubuntu 12.04 was out of date I updated their laptop to Ubuntu 14.04 64bit. Printer stopped working after that. I did a lot research about this problem, seems that Lexmark only provide Linux Drivers for Ubuntu 12.04 and doesnt support newer versions. Also tried drivers for newer Lexmark printers, but they aren't working. Lexmark Toolkit recognize the printer, with USB and Wifi, but can only store the USB connection, nit Wifi. But its impossible to print anything.
Anyone found a solution for this? Are there any universal drivers they can use as alternative?
Was so happy that they managed it to use Ubuntu after a lot trouble with Windows in the last year. Would be a blame if they have to change back to Windows.

Comment: Nobody knows anything? :(

Answer (score 0):

I got my Pinnacle Pro working with the following page:

http://daywalker313.blogspot.com.es/2012/07/lexmark-pinnacle-pro901-linux-driver.html

You need to save the ppd file mentioned there:

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B1TfEz4GUYOmQXF2Q2pudUdJZ1U

Somewhere on your compulter, This file has the settings for the printer.

First of all make sure Cups (Common Unix Printing Service) is working, you can check this by opening following page in your browser:

http://localhost:631

If it displays a page with the title "CUPS" and some blurb: 
"CUPS is the standards-based, open source printing system developed by Apple Inc. for OS® X and other UNIX®-like operating systems."

Then CUPS is properly installed.

Then:

- Plug in your printer
- Turn on wifi or networking on your computer
- System Settings > Select Printers > Add
- Select Network Printer
- Then select "Find Network Printer" wait a while it should come up
  with some options and then eventually an option "Lexmark
  Pro800-Pro900 (ip address)" Select that Lexmark printer, then on the right
  hand side select the option: "AppSocket/JetDirect network printer via
  DNS-SD"
- Click "Forward"
- A Box comes up saying "Searching for Drivers"
- If you are then prompted give them the location for the ppd file you
  saved previously on your computer
- Then it may come up with "Installable Options" "Tray 2", I didn't check this box
- "Describe Printer" Put in a Name, Description and Location for your printer
- Print Test Page

And then hopefully happy printing, I tried many different ways the stuff on the Lexmark site gave me bad quality package errors.  Eventually I found the page mentioned, many thanks to Daywalker's Blog!

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Since upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 my Lexmark Pro 901 stopped working.

AppAmor was the problem.

Solution:

```
vi /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.cupsd
```

add:

```
"...
  # Site-specific additions and overrides. See local/README for details.
  #include <local/usr.sbin.cupsd>
  # adding lexmark exception
  /usr/local/lexmark/** Ux,
}
..."

sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.cupsd
```

PS: Don't forget:

```
chmod 755 /usr/local/lexmark/v3/bin/printfilter
chgrp bin /usr/local/lexmark/v3/bin/*
```